# How to add c++ method definition automatically in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

Lets say I have a class A with its header and implementation files A.h and A.cpp, and I add a new method called "test" to A.h.

A.h :

```
class A{
   public:
      A();//constructor
      void test();
 }
```

is there a way in Sublime Text to automatically add the method "test" to the implementation file A.cpp, like Qt Creator in wich you can add the new method with right click->refactor->add definition in A.cpp